# Drake - how to visualize frame in LCM

Tags: drake

How do I visualize different coordinate frames in drake when using the LCM visualizer, such as the body frame attached to the end effector of the Kuka?

Comment: To clarify, I believe you mean `DrakeVisualizer`?  The visualizer is listening on channels `DRAKE_DRAW_FRAMES.*`, but I don't see any code in Drake that publishes to it.  We should probably push an example.  We definitely *do* have this feature in [MeshCat](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.meshcat_visualizer.html#pydrake.systems.meshcat_visualizer.MeshcatVisualizer).

Comment: Hi Professor, thank you for your comment!

Yes, I was referring to ```DrakeVisualizer```. I am aware that visualizing frame is doable in Meshcat. The reason why I switched to using ```DrakeVisuazlizer``` is because I need to render the cameras. Per the comment here [1], it sounds to me like rendering cameras in meshcat will fail. Is this true? I don't need to run drake inside docker.

[1] https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/478f1b04a476065b83b59273c7e028f816595bd3/examples/manipulation_station/end_effector_teleop_sliders.py#L257

Comment: Hi @RussTedrake, the documentation link you provided now 404s. Do you have updated information about how to accomplish this in Meshcat? I have posted a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683262/how-do-i-visualize-coordinate-frames-in-drake-using-meshcat

Comment: I believe this new question should have an updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683262/how-do-i-visualize-coordinate-frames-in-drake-using-meshcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some simple code for drawing frames in Drake Visualizer, w/ simple video: 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/ea2d7987/drake_stuff/drake_viz_draw_frames/README.md

Does this help at all? If so, yeah, I can help to PR against Drake.

---

Some notes / caveats:

- This doesn't draw `pydrake.geometry.FrameId` as does `meshcat`; instead, it simply draws a frame (whatever you name it) using `RigidTransform`, w.r.t. world frame.
- This is unlike things like `/tf` in ROS, where you can publish a frame w.r.t. another frame.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thank you for the code example and video. Very nicely put together!